# How to send a message from Spring WS application to WebSphere JMS Queue

Tags: web-services, ibm-mq, spring-ws, spring-jms, websphere-8

I am new to the Spring web service and Websphere application server.

i am working on spring web services and there is a requirement where as soon as a request comes, i need to send an XML message to the server where my web service is deployed, which is WebSphere application server in my case. i tried but did not get any concrete solution on this. i don't know what are the bean configuration has to be done for spring JMS and Web Sphere JMS MQ integration. Also, how to create a websphere JMS queue.

My environment related details are:

- Spring 3.1.0
- Spring-WS 2.0.2
- Websphere Application Server V8

let me know if more details are required.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring JMSTemplate to send JMS messages.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jms.html

Comment: Hi maximdim. i was looking for the some article which could help me to send message to websphere JMS Queue. i did not get much help from the link you have recommended. since i am new to the spring-ws and websphere, i don't know much about which websphere JMS queue to configure (Default Queue, Websphere Queue, V5 Queue..i could see these options in websphere admin console) and how to do the bean configuration for JNDI, Connection Factory, etc. in spring-WS bean configuration file. Do let me know if you have some example on this. Thanks.

Comment: Vishal, I think you need to rephrase your question (or two) then, or perhaps post new one about how to configure WebSphere queues and how to send JMS message. It has relatively little to do with Spring WS. Perhaps reading introductory article or book on JMS would also help

Comment: maximdim, Sorry for the late reply. My actual requirement is the question i have posted. As a beginner i couldn't make out much from post suggested by you. so thats why my comment could be confusing to you.I am looking for a straight forward example which tells these are the bean configuration required for spring JMS and web sphere MQs integration, also describes about the queues details in websphere.I searched but got confused whether WebSphere App Server JMS Queue configuration if enough or i need to use WebSphere MQ Server also,because app server don't give any info for messages in Queue.